# Installing sourcetools fails in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am having a problem installing sourcetools in R, which is one of the dependencies to install shiny.

R is in version 3.4.0.

Can you make heads and tails out of the following:

```
install.packages('sourcetools', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/sourcetools_0.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 16227 bytes (15 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 15 KB

* installing *source* package 'sourcetools' ...
** package 'sourcetools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -std=c++0x -I/home/tomgeo/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2 -c Reader.cpp -o Reader.o
g++ -std=c++0x -I/home/tomgeo/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2 -c Tokenizer.cpp -o Tokenizer.o
In file included from ../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/TokenCursor.h:7,
             from ../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/cursor.h:5,
             from ../inst/include/sourcetools.h:11,
             from Tokenizer.cpp:1:
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h: In constructor 'sourcetools::tokens::Token::Token()':
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:27: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h: In constructor 'sourcetools::tokens::Token::Token(sourcetools::tokens::TokenType)':
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:34: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h: In constructor 'sourcetools::tokens::Token::Token(const sourcetools::tokens::Token::Position&)':
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:41: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h: In function 'std::ostream& sourcetools::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<sourcetools::tokens::Token, std::allocator<sourcetools::tokens::Token> >&)':
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:457: error: expected initializer before ':' token
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:459: error: expected primary-expression before 'return'
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:459: error: expected ';' before 'return'
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:459: error: expected primary-expression before 'return'
../inst/include/sourcetools/tokenization/Token.h:459: error: expected ')' before 'return'
In file included from ../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/cursor.h:5,
             from ../inst/include/sourcetools.h:11,
             from Tokenizer.cpp:1:
../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/TokenCursor.h: In member function 'bool sourcetools::cursors::TokenCursor::moveToPosition(const sourcetools::cursors::TokenCursor::Position&)':
../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/TokenCursor.h:167: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/TokenCursor.h:167: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/TokenCursor.h:167: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
../inst/include/sourcetools/cursor/TokenCursor.h:167: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
make: *** [Tokenizer.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'sourcetools'
```

Comment: R version is `3.2.4` right? Also what is the OS and version

Comment: R version is 3.4.0 as stated in the initial posting. OS is CentOS 6

Comment: I am not sure how you have R 3.4.0, given that 3.2.4 is the latest version, and 3.3.0 is in prerelease right now.

Comment: That question is easy to answer: ftp://ftp.stat.math.ethz.ch/Software/R/R-devel_2016-03-30.tar.gz

Comment: It's most likely a bug or incompatibility with the pre-released R software. Use a stable version if possible.

Comment: What version of g++ are you using? It looks like the compiler is choking on nullptr, which wasn't supported until gcc 4.6.

Comment: Since nullptr was introduced in C++11 it could be necessary to change the Makefile and use the compiler flag `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=c++0x`. The latter may still work, but is outdated.

Comment: Indeed, the CRAN version of `sourcetools` requires a C++11 compiler. The next version of `sourcetools` will lift that restriction; if you want, you can install the development version from https://github.com/kevinushey/sourcetools.

Answer (score 2):

The version of `sourcetools` on CRAN requires a compiler with C++11 features. The development version lifts that restriction and attempts to adhere to the C++98 standard, so that it can build on older compilers.

You should be able to install the development version of [`sourcetools`](https://github.com/kevinushey/sourcetools) using e.g.

```
devtools::install_github("kevinushey/sourcetools")
```

If you still have trouble, please feel free to file an issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kevinushey/sourcetools).